# new File("/storage/").ListFile() return null on android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio

my app search on /storage folder to find external sd cards. its work on android phone < sdk 30.
but on android 30, I have problem when call line below:

```
new File("/storage").listFiles();
```

I wrote permissions for android 11:

in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in code:

```
if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
    else
        StartApp();
```

everything is OK but 'new File("/storage").listFiles()' return null

Comment: "but 'new File("/storage").listFiles()' return null" -- that is what I would expect it to return. If it returned something else previously, that was a bug, either with some specific device or possibly Android in general.

Comment: @CommonsWare , my app tested on android 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. and its work properly.

Comment: Then that was a security issue that Google finally closed. I would not expect you to have read access to `/storage`, but only perhaps to specific subdirectories of `/storage`.

Comment: so, how can I get list of my external SD cards?

Comment: Look into `StorageManager`.